# Picturebox drag and drop file name

Tags: vb.net, image, path, filenames, picturebox

I have set up a picturebox, where i drag and drop a picture. I also would like to know the name of this file. How can i do this?

Here is the current code below that handles the picture box:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub pb_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DragDrop
    Try
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), Array).GetValue(0).ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Doing Drag/Drop")
    End Try
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub

Private Sub pb_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DragEnter
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use three lines of code instead of one.  Dim files = CType(..) and Dim path = files(0)

Comment: thanks! it works =)